# Conditional formatting/Concatenating based on value in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, row, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two columns in excel file and save it to new column.
but i want to ignore the concatenation if one value is blank.
and move to next cell.

```
            Excel.Worksheet exampst = (Excel.Worksheet)Sh.get_Item("Sheet2");
            Excel.Range rng2 = (Excel.Range)exampst.get_Range("H1", Type.Missing);
            rng2.EntireColumn.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,                                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);
            exampst.Range["H1", Type.Missing].Value2 = "CombineID";
            Excel.Range rgcon2 = exampst.Range["H2"];
            //Excel.Range rng3 = (Excel.Range)RFCst.get_Range("G2", Type.Missing);
            //object obj = rng3.Value2;
            rgcon2.Formula = String.Format("=CONCATENATE(A2,G2)");
```

My excel sheet is like below.
`A1       G1    H1
1        a     1a  //this is the concatenated value.
2                  //This value b as null,as G1 column has missing row value.
3        b     3b
4        c     4c
5        d     5d
6

7        e     7e
8        f     8f 
9                     and so on....`

please help.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's the specific problem with your code?

Comment: lol.i want my code to do the concatation as showed.But it is not considering blank in G1 column.So if value in G1 exists,then concatenate and save result in H column.If not ,just igore the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Before concatenating, you need to check the value in cells in columns A and G first if they are null or empty.
You can do something like this:

```
object rangeObject = activeWorksheet.Cells[3, "A"];
Range range = (Range)rangeObject;
object rangeValue = range.Value2;
string cellValue1 = rangeValue.ToString();

rangeObject = activeWorksheet.Cells[3, "G"];
range = (Range)rangeObject;
rangeValue = range.Value2;
string cellValue2 = rangeValue.ToString();

if (cellValue1 != string.Empty && cellValue2 != string.Empty)
{
   //concatenate cells
}
```